# Update files images

Tags: php

I have code where I upload 6 images in one part of my site, that code worked fine, now, I need to update or change any image that was uploaded, I mean I need to change the image number 3 and 6, for example, so I wrote this code

```
$i=0;
    while ($i<=5){          
        if (!empty($_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]) and ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]<>"")){           
            $path[$i] = "../slider_new/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];  
            $path[$i] =  str_replace(' ', '_',$path[$i]);
            copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][$i], $path[$i]);
            echo "Ruta :".$path[$i]."<BR/>";
            echo "File Name :".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]."<BR/>"; 
            echo "este es $i ",$i;
            $sql="UPDATE accommo_main_images SET name='".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]."',ruta='".$path[$i]."' where num='$num'";
            $res=mysqli_query($cnx,$sql);     
        }
        $i=$i+1;        
    }
```

The idea is that check the name and when it is different to "" so..... update the image, that is the idea but I don´t know why the code update all the 6 images with the image that I selected.

What cam be the problem ?

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

> where num='$num'";

You use a SQL statement WHERE NUM=$num. Yet, you did not set $num anywhere in the code you gave us here. Most likely you never set the value of $num. You probally ment $i.
I'm guessing you also possibly made the same mistake in your upload code (initial upload) and therefor all images have number=0.
You are now updating images which have number 0, or empty string (depending on database field type) which would match every image you have in there.

Try running this code and check the table entries.

```
$res = mysqli_query($cnx,"SELECT num,name FROM accommo_main_images");
var_dump(mysqli_fetch_all($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Comment: Hi ... don´t worry about $num, It set in previous line in this fuction, I din´d add it because I think it isn´t necessary

Comment: It's still an issue, as you are updating up all rows, which have the id equal to $num. However, your $num does NOT change in the loop, so $num is equal for all the queries, and likely rows!

Comment: OK, but this line ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i]<>"") should be true only for the image that I added not for the rest of them, right ?

look, this id the var_dump fot ufiles
array (size=5)
  'name' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'ballena1.jpg' (length=12)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
      5 => string '' (length=0)

Look !! in this case only the first one need to be modify

Comment: Correct. (""<>"") is false as well as (null<>"") is also false. So yes, the if statement is fine, the sql is however not. Try adding a echo 'Image being updated'; and see how many times the loop is actually called.

Comment: Thisis strange... look I added the echo tha you said me and a var_dump andlook
array (size=5)
'name' => 
array (size=6)
0 => string '' (length=0)
1 => string '' (length=0)
2 => string '' (length=0)
3 => string '3.jpg' (length=5)
4 => string '' (length=0)
5 => string '' (length=0)
'type' => 
array (size=6)
0 => string '' (length=0)
1 => string '' (length=0)
2 => string '' (length=0)
3 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
4 => string '' (length=0)
5 => string '' (length=0)
Ruta :../slider_new/3.jpg
File Name :3.jpg
este es 3 3Image being updated

Comment: I assume this means your 'num' is null everywhere or an empty string? (Use a database tool and browse your table, e.g. phpmyadmin)

Comment: Is there a way to know which image I selected?, I mean ... how to know that the 4 was selected?
'name' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '56929-256x256-calendar-icon.png' (length=31)
      5 => string '' (length=0)